# Updating products after importing and publishing them

Tags: php, wordpress, web-scraping, woocommerce, product

I'm using Octolooks Scrapes for importing products into WooCommerce. Everything works fine, except stock status. Stock is scraped by the book. But when the product is published automatically, stock status is always set on "IN STOCK", although some of them are not. But then when I update the products manually, the stock is set as it suppose to be.

**Question:
Any suggestions on how to force product update in WooCommerce after it was published?**

**Examples:**

Before:
[Picture of stock status when imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFRim.png)

After:
[Picture of stock status when manually updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CQBb.png)

Comment: Clear transients and transient cache under woocommerce > status > tools. You can run this programmatically as well if there is any hook when import is finished

Comment: I've already tried and It doesn't help. And it doesn't help regenerating product lookup table data also

Answer (score 0):

```
wc_update_product_lookup_tables();
```

Try running this function after the import.

Comment: Try [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/) and do a single import - if it works

Comment: This solution partly works only if I don't manage the stock, If managing it is set to "no" and If I'm importing meta "instock" and "outofstock". But only has an effect on filtering products by stock in Woocommerce products dasboard and it doesn't have an effect on counting the same product in categories. In categories is still counted but not seen on the page. And alsoo doesnt work If I want to manage stock, in which case I'm importing quantity of the products... In this case helps only updating of products in Products - All products - "product" - Edit - Update.

Comment: Ok, I'll try with manual CSV import with this plugin and I'll let you know. Thx

Comment: Almost the same problem! I deactivated all plugins accept Wocommerce and Product Import Export for WooCommerce. And when I've imported the same products the only change was that **"In stock (0)"** was now marked as **"Out of stock (0)"** on Woocommerce dashboard. But It was still impossible to sort them by stock on dashboard and they are still counted in categories in Product filter on Shop page

Comment: With importing a **single product** with Product Import Export for WooCommerce, Lookup table is populated Product Import Export for WooCommerce. Sorting by stock is working. But It still counts "out of stock" products in categories on product filter

Comment: Try -  wp_cache_flush();
  wp_defer_term_counting( true );

Comment: It doesn't help... product still counted in categories on product filter. And I'm using two filters. Original from Woocommerce and from Themify, and both are showin the same.

Comment: And there' now another problem. Before when stock was showing **In stock (0)**, when I updated the product, stock was immediately **Out of stock (0)**, sorting was ok and also category count was as supposed to be. But now updating the product is not enaugh. Now I have to change the stock on 1 (In stock) and then back to 0 (out of stock) to except the changes..

Comment: Is there any function to update product after it was published?

Comment: You can call the save function with product object after the import  if there is any filter - $product->save();

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bit lost here, because I didn't understand your last answer and I don't know how to do that?